# Problemas com Drag and Drop em JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Estou com problemas com a minha função de Drag e Drop em JavaScript, o funcionamento do drag and drop está perfeito, porém quando troco algumas imagens, elas fazem a troca incorreta. Por exemplo: tenho as imagens x,y e z, e quando troco z e y, a troca ocorre em y e x e z fica no mesmo local.

```js
//esta função irá pegar o ID das imagens, para fazer a troca das imagens de acordo com o id delas

function pegaId(obj) {
var idCorreto = obj.getAttribute('id');
return idCorreto;
}

function drag(obj) {
 var zIndexImg = 0;
 // com a var id, eu detecto qual imagem está sendo arrastada
 var id = obj.getAttribute('id');

 var img = document.getElementById(id);
 var imgPositionLeft = img.offsetLeft;
 var imgPositionTop = img.offsetTop;

 img.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
 };

 function dropImage(e) {
  img.style.transition = "";
  img.style.zIndex = zIndexImg++;

  // faço o drag das imagens
  img.style.top = e.clientY - imgPositionTop + 'px';
  img.style.left = e.clientX - imgPositionLeft + 'px';

  console.log(e.clientX - imgPositionLeft);
 }

 function change(id1, id2, div1, div2) {
  // esta função realizara a troca das imagens
  img.removeAttribute('style');

  // atribuo as imagens e as divs em que estao guardadas em variaveis
  var imgDiv = document.getElementById(div1);
  var imgDiv_2 = document.getElementById(div2);
  var imgId = document.getElementById(id1);
  var imgId2 = document.getElementById(id2);

  // pego o id de ambas imagens
  var getId = imgId.getAttribute('id');
  var getId2 = imgId2.getAttribute('id');

  // faço a troca dos ids
  imgId.setAttribute('id', getId2);
  imgId2.setAttribute('id', getId);

  // e sobreponho as imagens nas divs, fazendo a troca
  imgDiv.innerHTML = imgId2.cloneNode().outerHTML;
  imgDiv_2.innerHTML = imgId.cloneNode().outerHTML;
 }

 function drop(e) {
  // esta função é para quando soltar as imagens
  dropImage(e);
  // removo os eventos adicionados
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', dropImage);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', drop);

  // descubro qual a imagem clicada para fazer a troca
  if (img.style.left >= '90px' && img.style.left <= '130px') {
   // pego o ID para saber qual a imagem
   if (pegaId(obj) == 'teste1') {

    // e faço a troca com a função change
    change("teste1", "teste2", "img1", "img2");

   } else if (pegaId(obj) == 'teste2') {
    change("teste2", "teste3", "img2", "img3");
   }

  }

  if (img.style.left >= '230px' && img.style.left <= '250px') {
   change("teste1", "teste3", "img1", "img3");

  }
  if (img.style.left >= '-115px' && img.style.left <= '-130px') {

   if (pegaId(obj) == 'teste3') {
    change("teste2", "teste3", "img2", "img3");
   } else if (pegaId(obj) == 'teste2') {
    change("teste2", "teste1", "img2", "img1");
   }
  }

  if (img.style.left >= '-225px' && img.style.left <= '-250px') {
   change("teste1", "teste3", "img1", "img3");
  }

  // reseto os valores após soltar a imagem
  img.style.left = '0px';
  img.style.top = '0px';
 }

 // adiciono os eventos novamente após clicar nas imagens
 img.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', dropImage);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', drop);
 });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v1u1xnwj/11/

Comment: Queres que a imagem arrastada troque de posição com a que está fixa ou inserir a arrastada e afastar as outras para o lado?

Comment: Quero que a que está sendo arrastada troque de lugar com a que está fixa no momento, porém gostaria de manter puro JavaScript sem jQuery...

Comment: @Sergio reinseri o jsFiddle !

Comment: Desculpe por ter removido o link @anuseranother

Comment: @re22 Sem problemas, também não havia notado, acontece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiquei que o meu problema ocorreu pois a mesma função que trocava as imagens estava trocando os ids, ocasionando nessa confusão em algumas trocas. Fiz a troca do ID em outra função e o problema deixou de existir, assim:

```
//função que troca as imagens de lugar
            function change(id1,id2,div1,div2){

                img.removeAttribute('style');

                var imgDiv = document.getElementById(div1);
                var imgDiv_2 = document.getElementById(div2);
                var imgId = document.getElementById(id1);
                var imgId2 = document.getElementById(id2);

                imgDiv.innerHTML = imgId2.cloneNode().outerHTML;
                imgDiv_2.innerHTML = imgId.cloneNode().outerHTML;
}

//função que troca o id das imagens
            function trocaId(id1,id2){
                var id_1 = document.getElementById(id1);
                var id_2 = document.getElementById(id2);

                    id_1.setAttribute('id',id2);
                    id_2.setAttribute('id',id1);
                }

//fazendo a troca

            if(img.style.left >= '250px' && img.style.left <= '290px'){
                if(pegaId(obj) == 'teste1'){
                    change("teste1","teste2","img1","img2");
                    trocaId("teste1","teste2");
                }else if(pegaId(obj) == 'teste2'){
                    change("teste2","teste3","img2","img3");
                    trocaId("teste2","teste3");
                }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v1u1xnwj/10/